# String constructor with a int is not printed

Tags: c++, string, constructor, initialization, initializer-list

```
    1. string s6 {0};
    2. string s5 {'a','b',7};
    cout << "S6 ::: " << s6 << endl; 
    cout << "S5 ::: " << s5 << endl;
```

1. Expect undefined behaviour 'nullptr' but does print an empty string.
2. Prints `ab` not expected behaviour.

Running on QT5.*.* compiler clang on MacOs

Comment: what do you mean with "Expect undefined behaviour.. " ? When there is ub you should not expect anything

Comment: what did you expect to get as ouput for 2)?

Comment: First, why do you expect undefined behaviour? Second, how would you know you're not observing undefined behaviour?

Comment: Try for second `{'a', 'b', 99}` and you'll see `abc` in output.

Comment: This why the common recommendation "always initialize with { }" can be a culprit...

Comment: sorry my bad this was rushed, it all makes sense Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In the both cases

```
1. string s6 {0};
2. string s5 {'a','b',7};
```

there is used the constructor that accepts an initializer list.

In the second case the integer literal 7 can be represented in the type char. So there is no narrowing conversion.

Consider the following program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string s6 {0};
    std::string s5 {'a','b',7};

    std::cout << s6.size() << ": ";

    for ( char c : s6 ) std::cout << static_cast<int>( c ) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << s5.size() << ": ";

    for ( char c : s5 ) std::cout << static_cast<int>( c ) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1: 0 
3: 97 98 7
```